# Loand data com ENUM

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use ENUM together with a LOAND DATA?

I need to check the items at the moment I'm loading the data. I found a way to define these items at the time of creating the table but there is a possibility that some of them will undergo a naming change and as the base is huge it will take a long time to do this...

This is the file I'm trying to load

[image]

I'm using the code below to load the data

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/sql/vendas/teste.txt'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE vds_isiz
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
-- OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET
**Produto =ENUM('VIVO ','ZTV'),**
CPFCNPJ = LPAD(CPFCNPJ,11,0)
;
```

I'm getting the error below exactly on line 9 which is the **ENUM**

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('VIVO','ZTV'),
 CPFCNPJ = LPAD(CPFCNPJ,11,0)' at line 9    0.000 sec
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Investigate correct syntax in Reference Manual. PS. ENUM value can be loaded without problems.

Answer (score 0):

`ENUM('VIVO ','ZTV')` belongs in the `CREATE TABLE`

`"VIVO"` (or `"ZTV"`) belongs in the file -- as you have it.  And, yes, the `LOAD DATA` needs `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'` because of the quotes in the file.